# Django's Cast function returns DataError: invalid input syntax for type integer: "John"

Tags: python, django

I have the following models that allow me to dynamically create and track data for a contact:

```
class DataField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Contact(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField()

class ContactField(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    data_field= models.ForeignKey(DataField)
    value = models.CharField()
```

For example I have two DataField models with the name field set as "First Name" and "Loan Amount".  To create data for a contact, I create two ContactFields, the first I link to the "First Name" data field and give it the value "John", the second I link to the "Loan Amount" data field and give it the value 5000. e.g:

```
ContactField(1)
  contact = Contact(1)
  data_field = DataField(First Name)
  value = "John"

ContactField(2)
  contact = Contact(1)
  data_field = DataField(Loan Amount)
  value = "5000"
```

Now I want to query the database to return Contacts that have a loan amount greater than X.  The first problem is that the value field needs to be an integerfield to perform the greater than query, but it is a CharField.  I cannot change it to an integer field because it needs to store both integers and strings (e.g it also stores the value "John" for first name).

As a result I am trying to use the annotate and cast functions from django to create a new column "value_int" for the query, so I can perform greater than queries:

```
# get all "Loan Amount" contact fields that exist
queryset = ContactField.objects.filter(data_field__name="Loan Amount")

# add a value_int field
value_int_queryset = queryset.annotate("value_int": Cast("value", output_field=IntegerField()))

# filter based on value_int field, only returning ids that match query
ids_matching= value_int_queryset.filter(value_int__gt=X).values_list('id')

# return contacts that the contact fields belong to:
contacts = Contact.objects.filter(contact_field__in=ids_matching)
```

This returns django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type integer: "John".  So even though I filter for Loan Amount fields at the start, Django is still trying to cast first names as well.  I think this is due to django querysets being lazy, so it casts value int before (or at the same time) that it filters out the first name field.

I tried forcing the queryset to evaluate before it casts the integer column using len() (as mentioned in the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/), but I still get the same error:

```
# get all "Loan Amount" contact fields that exist
queryset = ContactField.objects.filter(data_field__name="Loan Amount")

len(queryset)

# add a value_int field
value_int_queryset = queryset.annotate("value_int": Cast("value", output_field=IntegerField()))
```

So I am a bit confused at how I can prevent the First Name ContactField from being included in the Cast command.  Even if I iterate over the contact fields I can see that all the value fields are an integer, and John isn't included:

```
# get all "Loan Amount" contact fields that exist
queryset = ContactField.objects.filter(data_field__name="Loan Amount")

len(queryset)
for field in queryset:
    print(field.value) # only prints number based strings e,g 5000.  John never shows up here

# add a value_int field
value_int_queryset = queryset.annotate("value_int": Cast("value", output_field=IntegerField()))
```

Still get the same error as before though

Comment: In `ContactField` you have made the typo, it is `Models` not `Moddels`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question, but this error is not in my original code